# Excel dynamic graph in a picture

Tags: excel, dynamic, graph

I'm building a dashboard in Excel, and I have an example file that has a very slick picture object that is actually a dynamic graph that updates based on value selected in a separate listbox control. The value of the picture is simply "=SelChart". This file has no macros, and I can't locate any defined range, hidden tabs, data connections, etc. that helps me understand the source data, and how this picture dynamically refreshes itself (again, this is NOT a Graph object, it is a picture). Any insight on how this might work? I'd attach the file, but this website apparently decided attachment functionality is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's a formula referring to a named range. Go to the formulas tab on the ribbon and click on the Name Manager button and you may find the answer there.

Comment: No, I had already checked that. FYI, this dashboard's author was using VBA property of "very hidden" to hide worksheets that couldn't be un-hidden with regular Excel "unhide" command. Still don't understand this dynamic picture-graph thing...

Comment: Have you un-hidden those sheets yet as it really sounds like it's a picture created with the camera tool that's referring to the named range you described in the OP and if they're still Very Hidden then the range could be on one of those.